# Compacted 8910 after heavy rains

Tags: retaining-wall

I am working on a retaining wall. My footer is 18” deep x 24” wide. I have a compacted layer of 8910 that is 6” deep placed in 2 lifts and compacted well after each lift. It felt pretty solid. Started laying base row using hand tamper during install as well to confirm compaction of base. All was going well until the last two days of rain. Now the compacted base has soften up some. Will this dry out and harden back up or am I stuck starting over? TIA

DIYer but too stubborn to hire. LOL

Comment: You may want to explain what "8910" is for those not in the know... Of course, those not in the know won't be answering the question, but they may be learning something.

Comment: Thx 4 the response. For those uncertain, 8910 is a type of Crusher Run gravel used for base layers like those found in footers.